# Highcharts best way to update dynamically changing exporting values?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a grouped column highchart with drilldown capability. It's for a school district, so my grouped columns are prior-year/current-year for Elementary, Middle, and High school level stats.  You can click on any of the columns to drill down and see how the individual schools are doing. Upon exporting the chart, I'm trying to make several changes depending on which school level has been selected -- the width and height of the chart, x axis categories, and category rotation.

I was hoping to be able to make these changes dynamically within the chart.events section, but it does not seem to be working.  I'm initially my dynamic variables outside of the initial chart build, and those values are being used. Obviously I'm not doing something right. Is there an easier way to update these values for the exporting method that I just don't know about?

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/BigSexy/qx5uzdf6/50/) of the chart so you can see what's going on...any help you can provide, as always, would be greatly appreciated!!

```
cats = categoriesSL.slice();
categoryHeight = 300;
categoryWidth = 500;
categoryRotation = 0;

//Build The Chart
var refChart = new Highcharts.chart('ctReferrals', {
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'whiteSmoke',
        events: {
            drilldown: function () {
                categoryHeight = 400;
                categoryRotation = 90;

                switch (this.ddDupes[0]) {
                    case 'elem':
                    case 'elem2':
                        cats = categoriesElem.slice();
                        categoryCount = categoriesElem.length - 1;
                        categoryWidth = 6000;
                        refChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesElem);
                        break;
                    case 'mid':
                    case 'mid2':
                        cats = categoriesMid.slice();
                        categoryCount = categoriesMid.length - 1;
                        categoryWidth = 2500;
                        refChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesMid);
                        break;
                    case 'high':
                    case 'high2':
                        cats = categoriesHigh.slice();
                        categoryCount = categoriesHigh.length - 1;
                        categoryWidth = 2000;
                        refChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesHigh);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

                refChart.xAxis[0].update({ max: 5 }, true);

                this.update({
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: true,
                    }
                }, false);
            },
            drillupall: function () {
                cats = categoriesSL.slice();
                categoryHeight = 300;
                categoryWidth = 500;
                categoryRotation = 0;
                categoryCount = categoriesSL.length - 1;

                refChart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoriesSL);
                refChart.xAxis[0].update({ max: categoriesSL.length - 1 }, true);

                this.update({
                    scrollbar: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }, false);
            }
        },
        type: 'column',
    },
    title: {
        text: title
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: subTitle
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: categoriesSL,
        min: 0,
        max: categoriesSL.length - 1,
    },
    yAxis: [{
        title: {
            useHtml: true,
            text: '<strong># Referrals</strong>'
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            borderRadius: 5,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
            },
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: dataLabels[0],
        data: pySL
    }, {
        name: dataLabels[1],
        data: cySL
    }],
    drilldown: {
        allowPointDrilldown: false,
        series: [
            pyElem,
            cyElem,
            pyMid,
            cyMid,
            pyHigh,
            cyHigh
        ]
    },
    exporting: {
        chartOptions: {
            chart: {
                width: categoryHeight,
                height: categoryWidth,
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: cats,
                labels: {
                    rotation: categoryRotation
                },
                max: categoryCount,
            }]
        },
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I asked this question on the highcharts community board yesterday and somebody answered this question on it...basically I needed to add .update() in the chart events section.  I've done it and everything is working perfectly now!!

Here's a link to the answer and a working [jsFiddle](https://forum.highcharts.com/post143765.html?sid=82795fa88eaa6b4b795ae571fd90ac07#p143765):